# Rails: ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 0..1)):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

In only `production` environment I get following errors.

```
[81bedcfb-4b75-445c-b56e-ce17a1c477db] app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:17
I, [2022-06-30T14:05:56.938148 #71839]  INFO -- : [ae44ac69-b517-40d4-9022-32d48befe086] Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-06-30 14:05:56 +0800
I, [2022-06-30T14:05:56.939300 #71839]  INFO -- : [ae44ac69-b517-40d4-9022-32d48befe086] Processing by DashboardController#index as HTML
I, [2022-06-30T14:05:56.942026 #71839]  INFO -- : [ae44ac69-b517-40d4-9022-32d48befe086]   Rendered dashboard/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 4)
I, [2022-06-30T14:05:56.943254 #71839]  INFO -- : [ae44ac69-b517-40d4-9022-32d48befe086]   Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 1.4ms | Allocations: 647)
I, [2022-06-30T14:05:56.943428 #71839]  INFO -- : [ae44ac69-b517-40d4-9022-32d48befe086] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms | Allocations: 1418)
F, [2022-06-30T14:05:56.945594 #71839] FATAL -- : [ae44ac69-b517-40d4-9022-32d48befe086]   
[ae44ac69-b517-40d4-9022-32d48befe086] ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 0..1)):
[ae44ac69-b517-40d4-9022-32d48befe086]     1: <nav aria-label="breadcrumb" class="-intro-x h-[45px] mr-auto">
[ae44ac69-b517-40d4-9022-32d48befe086]     2:   <ol class="breadcrumb breadcrumb-light">
[ae44ac69-b517-40d4-9022-32d48befe086]     3:     <li class="breadcrumb-item">
[ae44ac69-b517-40d4-9022-32d48befe086]     4:       <%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
[ae44ac69-b517-40d4-9022-32d48befe086]     5:     </li>
[ae44ac69-b517-40d4-9022-32d48befe086]     6: 
[ae44ac69-b517-40d4-9022-32d48befe086]     7:     <% breadcrumbs.each_with_index do |item, index| %>
[ae44ac69-b517-40d4-9022-32d48befe086]   
[ae44ac69-b517-40d4-9022-32d48befe086] app/views/shared/_breadcrumb.html.erb:4
[ae44ac69-b517-40d4-9022-32d48befe086] app/views/shared/_topbar.html.erb:11
```

Below errors  only occurs on routes /for example:  root_path, dashboard_path etc./.

Here is the my `router.rb`

```
# require 'sidekiq/web'

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # post "/graphql", to: "graphql#execute"
  root 'dashboard#index'

  # authenticate :admin do
  #   mount Sidekiq::Web => "/sidekiq"
  #   mount GraphiQL::Rails::Engine, at: "/graphiql", graphql_path: "/graphql"
  # end

  resources :organizations do
    collection do
      get :users
    end

    member do
      post :admins, to: 'organizations/tabs#admins'
      post :customers, to: 'organizations/tabs#customers'
      post :addresses, to: 'organizations/tabs#addresses'
    end
  end

  resources :users

  namespace :finance do
    resources :accounts
    resources :transactions, except: [:edit, :update]
  end

  resources :lawyers do
    resources :settings, controller: 'lawyers/settings', only: [:index, :update]
    resources :timetables, controller: 'lawyers/timetables'
    resources :transactions, controller: 'lawyers/transactions', except: [:edit, :update]
    resources :educations, controller: 'lawyers/educations'
    resources :work_experiences, controller: 'lawyers/work_experiences'
    resources :authentications, controller: 'lawyers/authentications', only: [:index, :new, :create]
    resources :comments, controller: 'lawyers/comments', only: [:index, :destroy]
    resources :ratings, controller: 'lawyers/ratings', except: [:edit, :update]
  end

  namespace :listens do
    resources :taxons
    resources :audios
  end

  namespace :settings do
    resources :banners
    resources :evaluations
    resources :sms_logs, only: [:index, :update, :destroy]
    resources :services
    resources :admins
    resources :questions
    resources :categories
  end

  devise_for :users
  devise_for :lawyers

  devise_for :admins, path: 'auth',
                      path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', password: 'secret', confirmation: 'verification', unlock: 'unblock' }

  #  root 'dashboard#index'
  post "/graphql", to: "graphql#execute"

  # authenticate :admin do
    # mount Sidekiq::Web => "/sidekiq"
    # mount GraphiQL::Rails::Engine, at: "/graphiql", graphql_path: "/graphql"
  # end

  # match '/404', to: 'errors#not_found', via: :all
  # match '/500', to: 'errors#internal_server_error', via: :all
end
```

I'm using ruby 3.1.2 and here is my app environment:

```
Gems included by the bundle:
  * actioncable (7.0.3)
  * actionmailbox (7.0.3)
  * actionmailer (7.0.3)
  * actionpack (7.0.3)
  * actiontext (7.0.3)
  * actionview (7.0.3)
  * active_storage_validations (0.9.8)
  * activejob (7.0.3)
  * activemodel (7.0.3)
  * activerecord (7.0.3)
  * activestorage (7.0.3)
  * activesupport (7.0.3)
  * airbrussh (1.4.0)
  * ancestry (4.2.0)
  * auto_increment (1.5.2)
  * bcrypt (3.1.17)
  * bindex (0.8.1)
  * bootsnap (1.11.1)
  * builder (3.2.4)
  * capistrano (3.17.0)
  * capistrano-bundler (2.1.0)
  * capistrano-passenger (0.2.1)
  * capistrano-rails (1.6.2)
  * capistrano-rbenv (2.2.0)
  * capistrano-sidekiq (2.3.0)
  * childprocess (4.1.0)
  * concurrent-ruby (1.1.10)
  * connection_pool (2.2.5)
  * crass (1.0.6)
  * cypress-on-rails (1.13.1)
  * database_cleaner-active_record (2.0.1)
  * database_cleaner-core (2.0.1)
  * datev (0.11.0)
  * debug (1.4.0)
  * devise (4.8.1)
  * digest (3.1.0)
  * erubi (1.10.0)
  * factory_bot (6.2.1)
  * factory_bot_rails (6.2.0)
  * faker (2.21.0 4255812)
  * ffi (1.15.5)
  * globalid (1.0.0)
  * graphiql-rails (1.8.0)
  * graphql (2.0.11)
  * i18n (1.10.0)
  * image_processing (1.12.2)
  * inline_svg (1.8.0)
  * io-console (0.5.11)
  * irb (1.4.1)
  * jbuilder (2.11.5)
  * jsbundling-rails (1.0.2)
  * jwt (2.3.0)
  * keepr (0.7.0)
  * loofah (2.18.0)
  * mail (2.7.1)
  * marcel (1.0.2)
  * method_source (1.0.0)
  * mini_magick (4.11.0)
  * mini_mime (1.1.2)
  * minitest (5.15.0)
  * msgpack (1.4.5)
  * net-imap (0.2.3)
  * net-pop (0.1.1)
  * net-protocol (0.1.3)
  * net-scp (3.0.0)
  * net-smtp (0.3.1)
  * net-ssh (6.1.0)
  * nio4r (2.5.8)
  * nokogiri (1.13.6)
  * orm_adapter (0.5.0)
  * pagy (5.10.1)
  * pg (1.3.5)
  * puma (5.6.4)
  * racc (1.6.0)
  * rack (2.2.3)
  * rack-cors (1.1.1)
  * rack-test (1.1.0)
  * rails (7.0.3)
  * rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
  * rails-html-sanitizer (1.4.2)
  * railties (7.0.3)
  * rake (13.0.6)
  * ransack (3.2.1)
  * redis (4.6.0)
  * reline (0.3.1)
  * responders (3.0.1)
  * rexml (3.2.5)
  * ruby-vips (2.1.4)
  * rubyzip (2.3.2)
  * sassc (2.4.0)
  * sassc-rails (2.1.2)
  * selenium-webdriver (4.1.0)
  * sidekiq (6.5.1)
  * sprockets (4.0.3)
  * sprockets-rails (3.4.2)
  * sshkit (1.21.2)
  * stimulus-rails (1.0.4)
  * strscan (3.0.1)
  * thor (1.2.1)
  * tilt (2.0.10)
  * timeout (0.2.0)
  * turbo-rails (1.1.1)
  * tzinfo (2.0.4)
  * view_component (2.57.1)
  * warden (1.2.9)
  * web-console (4.2.0)
  * webdrivers (5.0.0)
  * websocket-driver (0.7.5)
  * websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
  * zeitwerk (2.5.4)
Use `bundle info` to print more detailed information about a gem
```

Any idea?

**UPDATED**: `_breadcrumb.html.erb`

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb" class="-intro-x h-[45px] mr-auto">
  <ol class="breadcrumb breadcrumb-light">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
      <%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
    </li>

    <% breadcrumbs.each_with_index do |item, index| %>
      <% if index == breadcrumbs.size - 1 %>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page"><%= item.name %></li>
      <% else %>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item" aria-current="page"><%= link_to item.name, item.path %></li>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

_topbar.html.erb

```
<!-- BEGIN: Top Bar -->
<div class="top-bar-boxed h-[70px] md:h-[65px] z-[51] border-b border-white/[0.08] -mt-7 md:mt-0 -mx-3 sm:-mx-8 md:-mx-0 px-3 md:border-b-0 relative md:fixed md:inset-x-0 md:top-0 sm:px-8 md:px-10 md:pt-10 md:bg-gradient-to-b md:from-slate-100 md:to-transparent dark:md:from-darkmode-700">
  <div class="h-full flex items-center">
    <!-- BEGIN: Logo -->
    <a href="" class="logo -intro-x hidden md:flex xl:w-[180px] block">
      <%= image_tag 'logo.svg', class: 'w-6' %>
      <span class="logo__text text-white text-lg ml-3"> Enigma </span>
    </a>
    <!-- END: Logo -->
    <!-- BEGIN: Breadcrumb -->
    <%= render partial: 'shared/breadcrumb' %>
    <!-- END: Breadcrumb -->

    <!-- BEGIN: Account Menu -->
    <div class="intro-x dropdown w-8 h-8">
      <div class="dropdown-toggle w-8 h-8 rounded-full overflow-hidden shadow-lg image-fit zoom-in scale-110" role="button" aria-expanded="false" data-tw-toggle="dropdown">
        <%= image_tag "profile.jpg" %>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown-menu w-56">
        <ul class="dropdown-content bg-primary/80 before:block before:absolute before:bg-black before:inset-0 before:rounded-md before:z-[-1] text-white">
          <li class="p-2">
            <div class="font-medium">Arnold Schwarzenegger</div>
            <div class="text-xs text-white/60 mt-0.5 dark:text-slate-500">Software Engineer</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <hr class="dropdown-divider border-white/[0.08]">
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="" class="dropdown-item hover:bg-white/5"> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" icon-name="user" data-lucide="user" class="lucide lucide-user w-4 h-4 mr-2"><path d="M20 21v-2a4 4 0 00-4-4H8a4 4 0 00-4 4v2"></path><circle cx="12" cy="7" r="4"></circle></svg> Profile </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="" class="dropdown-item hover:bg-white/5"> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" icon-name="edit" data-lucide="edit" class="lucide lucide-edit w-4 h-4 mr-2"><path d="M11 4H4a2 2 0 00-2 2v14a2 2 0 002 2h14a2 2 0 002-2v-7"></path><path d="M18.5 2.5a2.121 2.121 0 013 3L12 15l-4 1 1-4 9.5-9.5z"></path></svg> Add Account </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="" class="dropdown-item hover:bg-white/5"> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" icon-name="lock" data-lucide="lock" class="lucide lucide-lock w-4 h-4 mr-2"><rect x="3" y="11" width="18" height="11" rx="2" ry="2"></rect><path d="M7 11V7a5 5 0 0110 0v4"></path></svg> Reset Password </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="" class="dropdown-item hover:bg-white/5"> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" icon-name="help-circle" data-lucide="help-circle" class="lucide lucide-help-circle w-4 h-4 mr-2"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><path d="M9.09 9a3 3 0 015.83 1c0 2-3 3-3 3"></path><line x1="12" y1="17" x2="12.01" y2="17"></line></svg> Help </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <hr class="dropdown-divider border-white/[0.08]">
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="" class="dropdown-item hover:bg-white/5"> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" icon-name="toggle-right" data-lucide="toggle-right" class="lucide lucide-toggle-right w-4 h-4 mr-2"><rect x="1" y="5" width="22" height="14" rx="7" ry="7"></rect><circle cx="16" cy="12" r="3"></circle></svg> Logout </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END: Account Menu -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATED:** Added full trace

```
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:169:in `url_for'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:271:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:214:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:327:in `block in define_url_helper'
app/views/shared/_breadcrumb.html.erb:4
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/base.rb:244:in `public_send'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/base.rb:244:in `_run'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in `block in render'
activesupport (7.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:208:in `instrument'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:361:in `instrument_render_template'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:155:in `render'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:251:in `block in render_partial_template'
activesupport (7.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (7.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (7.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `instrument'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:246:in `render_partial_template'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:237:in `render'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:81:in `render_partial_to_object'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:27:in `render_to_object'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:22:in `render'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:37:in `block in render'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/base.rb:270:in `in_rendering_context'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:33:in `render'
app/views/shared/_topbar.html.erb:11
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/base.rb:244:in `public_send'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/base.rb:244:in `_run'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in `block in render'
activesupport (7.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:208:in `instrument'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:361:in `instrument_render_template'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:155:in `render'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:251:in `block in render_partial_template'
activesupport (7.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (7.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (7.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `instrument'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:246:in `render_partial_template'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:237:in `render'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:81:in `render_partial_to_object'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:27:in `render_to_object'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:22:in `render'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:37:in `block in render'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/base.rb:270:in `in_rendering_context'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:33:in `render'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:17
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/base.rb:244:in `public_send'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/base.rb:244:in `_run'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in `block in render'
activesupport (7.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:208:in `instrument'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:361:in `instrument_render_template'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:155:in `render'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:76:in `block in render_with_layout'
activesupport (7.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (7.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (7.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `instrument'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:74:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:59:in `render_template'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:11:in `render'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:61:in `render_template_to_object'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:29:in `render_to_object'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:117:in `block in _render_template'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/base.rb:270:in `in_rendering_context'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:116:in `_render_template'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:216:in `_render_template'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:46:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:141:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `render'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in render'
/Users/zoloo/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/benchmark.rb:311:in `realtime'
activesupport (7.0.3) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:14:in `ms'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:22:in `block in render'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:91:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (7.0.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:34:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:21:in `render'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:35:in `default_render'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `block in send_action'
<internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:215:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:53:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (7.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
actiontext (7.0.3) lib/action_text/rendering.rb:20:in `with_renderer'
actiontext (7.0.3) lib/action_text/engine.rb:69:in `block (4 levels) in <class:Engine>'
activesupport (7.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `instance_exec'
activesupport (7.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `block in run_callbacks'
activesupport (7.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:138:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:233:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:67:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (7.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (7.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (7.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `instrument'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:66:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:259:in `process_action'
activerecord (7.0.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:151:in `process'
actionview (7.0.3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:188:in `dispatch'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:251:in `dispatch'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:852:in `call'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/http/permissions_policy.rb:38:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:36:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:697:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
activesupport (7.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:99:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:26:in `call'
railties (7.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:40:in `call_app'
railties (7.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `block in call'
activesupport (7.0.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:114:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (7.0.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:38:in `tagged'
activesupport (7.0.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:114:in `tagged'
railties (7.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:93:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:131:in `call'
rack-cors (1.1.1) lib/rack/cors.rb:100:in `call'
railties (7.0.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:530:in `call'
puma (5.6.4) lib/puma/configuration.rb:252:in `call'
puma (5.6.4) lib/puma/request.rb:77:in `block in handle_request'
puma (5.6.4) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:340:in `with_force_shutdown'
puma (5.6.4) lib/puma/request.rb:76:in `handle_request'
puma (5.6.4) lib/puma/server.rb:441:in `process_client'
puma (5.6.4) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:147:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: as the log mentions that in somewhere there must be a method call with 4 parameters but it is not. something odd here.

Comment: @MehmetAdilİstikbal yep, but I have no idea :( App is working normal in development mode

Comment: there might be a chance that when you deployed the new code to the production and somehow in production rails server still running with old code. In this case server would still getting this error while the codebase in production is up to date with your development. Becasue in production mode there won't be autoloading files on any change in them.

Comment: Thanks for hint. but already tried it.  Do you know any debug tool for this situation ?

Comment: BTW errors only occurred when I use `path`-s. For example `root_path`, `home_path` etc.

Comment: @Zeck, you can enable logger in the application.rb and see all of the auto-loaded classes. Maybe the application is loading the different file. Is there any chance to upload your code to GitHub?

Comment: @Dalai no sorry. I added full trace.

Answer (score 0):

Hold the door.
Ain't the syntax for root in routes.rb file:

`root to: 'dashboard#index'`

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: I included something in `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`. So that's why I'm getting below errors